# How made umbrella chart update existing helm deployment

Tags: charts, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, umbrella

I have a umbrella chart and I want to know if it's possible to update an existing helm deployment through my requirements.yaml in my umbrella chart.
[image: First app tier should be updated by my umbrella chart, not creating a new one.]

[image: First, app tier chart and second, my umbrellar chart containing app tier]

Answer (score 3):

Not directly. If you did some kind of funky CRD with one of the existing Helm operators then maybe, but overall releases don't know about each other.

Comment: Not at all, if you deploy a dependency using umbrella chart, then you can upgrade a this dependency with another single deploy, not using umbrella. I can't update a deployment with umbrella but another chart can do it with a deploy created by umbrella.